# THREE JS geometry verticles set by known angle

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to draw a triangle and i know only all angles (Alpha,Beta,Gamma) and all side length (10).

For drawing a triangle i need to set 3 vertices to geometry with absolute Vector3 values.

Is in THREE.js any integrated tool or practice fit for this?

```
geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3( 0,  0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, -10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(  10, -10, 0 ),
);
geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ));
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Only THREE method i can imagine is to create a 2 vector geometry with vector distance of side lengths, use matrix translation to set rotation pivot on vector[0] and change its position and rotation, each time set globalToWorld() for its vector[1]. But I think this is not a good solution.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to achieve this. I'm assuming you're only looking for the one that applies to your homework assignment?

Comment: Searching for integrated THREE,js method for fastest calculation for drawing thousands of this

Comment: @Berthur That is the same method, always need to know 3 absolute vectors, i have only one point (for start position) and angles with sides lengths.

Comment: @Martin Could you clarify your question with pictures, if possible?

Comment: It looks like you already have a solution to your problem, @Martin Not sure what else you're trying to achieve. You might want to try `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry`, but other than that, there's no alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
var length = 10;
var aplpha = 0.3;//rad
var beta= 1;//rad
geometry.vertices.push(
      new THREE.Vector3(),
      new THREE.Vector3(length ,0,0).applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0),aplpha ),
      new THREE.Vector3(length ,0,0).applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0),beta ),
      new THREE.Vector3(),
);
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3

THREE.JS r 96